# join 3 table in mondrian

Tags: xml, join, olap, cube, mondrian

```
<Schema name="Budget" description="BUDGET REPORT">
  <Dimension type="StandardDimension" visible="true" highCardinality="false" name="Time 2015">
    <Hierarchy visible="true" hasAll="true" allMemberName="Year" primaryKey="id">
      <Table name="time_dimension">
      </Table>
      <Level name="Year" visible="true" column="year" type="String" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="Regular" hideMemberIf="Never">
      </Level>
      <Level name="Month" visible="true" column="month_name" type="String" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="Regular" hideMemberIf="Never">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
  </Dimension>
  <Cube name="Report" visible="true" cache="false" enabled="true">
    <Table name="fact_product_individual">
    </Table>
    <Dimension type="StandardDimension" visible="true" foreignKey="pdt_id" highCardinality="false" name="All Products">
      <Hierarchy name="All Products" visible="false" hasAll="true" allMemberName="All Products" primaryKey="p_id" primaryKeyTable="fact_bgt_2015">
        <Join leftKey="p_id" rightAlias="pdt_individual" rightKey="pdt_id">
          <Table name="fact_bgt_2015">
          </Table>
          <Join leftKey="pgd_id" rightAlias="pro_grouping" rightKey="pg_id">
            <Table name="fact_product_individual" alias="pro_individual">
            </Table>
            <Table name="mis_product_grouping" alias="pro_grouping">
            </Table>
          </Join>
        </Join>
        <Level name="Product Name" visible="true" table="fact_bgt_2015" column="product_name" type="String" uniqueMembers="true" levelType="Regular" hideMemberIf="Never">
        </Level>
        <Level name="Sum value" visible="true" table="pro_grouping" column="group_label" type="String" uniqueMembers="true" levelType="Regular" hideMemberIf="Never">
        </Level>
        <Level name="category" visible="true" table="pro_grouping" column="pg_name" type="String" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="Regular" hideMemberIf="Never">
        </Level>
      </Hierarchy>
    </Dimension>
    <Measure name="Actual" column="actual" formatString="#,###.00" aggregator="sum" visible="true">
    </Measure>
    <Measure name="Budget" column="budget" formatString="#,###.00" aggregator="sum" visible="true">
    </Measure>
    <Measure name="Previous" column="prev" formatString="#,###.00" aggregator="sum" visible="true">
    </Measure>
    <CalculatedMember name="% Growth" formula="((([Measures].[Actual]-[Measures].[Previous])/[Measures].[Previous])*100)" dimension="Measures" visible="true">
    </CalculatedMember>
    <CalculatedMember name="% Variation to Budget" formula="((([Measures].[Budget]-[Measures].[Actual])/[Measures].[Actual])*100)" dimension="Measures" visible="true">
    </CalculatedMember>
  </Cube>
</Schema>
```

**Tables:**

1. fact_bgt_2015 (sp_id ,order_id ,p_id ,product_name ,cur_quantity ,cur_price ,prev_quantity ,prev_price ,bgt_quantity ,bgt_price ,p_ln ,p_cat ,p_scat ,p_division ,time_id ,p_mon ,p_year ,p_fyear)
2. fact_product_individual(fr_id ,pgd_id ,pdt_id ,time_id ,prev ,actual ,budget)
3. mis_product_grouping(pg_id ,pg_name ,group_label)

I want **Product Name->Sum Value->Category**

Its showing

> Error:failed to match primary key table to join tables.

Comment: Are you able to provide the DB schema for the above cube?